# $_POST on the same document as the form

Tags: php, html, html-input, forms, http-post

I have a problem with html forms and PHP on the same page. This is a part of the code I just wrote:

Here is the form where I want to insert the ID in an array by clicking the submit button. When I submit the form, the value for *menge* is always empty. Does somebody know why this problem occurs?

```
echo '<form name="aanzahl" method="POST" action="index.php?page=einzelansicht&id='.$a_id.'">';
echo '<input id="inputButton" type="text" name="menge" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2" disabled>';
echo '<input type="submit"  class ="warenkorbbtn" name="warenkorbbtn" value="In den Warenkorb">';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST['warenkorbbtn'])){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['warenkorb'])){
        $_SESSION['warenkorb'] = array();
    }

    $_SESSION['warenkorb'][] = array('warenkorb_id'=>$a_id, 'menge'=>$_POST['menge']);
    echo "Artikel befindet sich nun im Warenkorb";
}
```

Comment: One problem would be that you have "disabled" on the input "menge"...

Comment: even before check the code I hop you have session_start() at the top of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form element with attribute *disabled* will not have its value sent with the form:

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. Also, a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled)</sup>

In order to have the value sent with the form yet still prevent the user from modifying the value, use the attribute [***readonly***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-readonly) (though nothing can prevent the user from altering/removing that attribute with their browser console).

```
<input id="inputButton" type="text" name="menge" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2" readonly />
```

And if you don't care about the user even seeing the input, you could make the input type *hidden* (i.e. (`input type="hidden" />`), though the user could still change the value using their browser console.

You can see the readonly property demonstrated with [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2w3c-u8na), where the *readonly* attribute has been set on that input.

Also note that an *input* element has no permitted content and thus is an [empty element], so I added the slash to the end of the element in order to close it properly (i.e. `<input..../>`).

> In HTML, using a closing tag on an empty element is usually invalid. For example,  is invalid HTML.<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element)</sup>

Comment: Tank you! Now it works. But I want the field to be not changable. Is there a way to still do that?

Comment: Refer to the section of my answer about the [_readonly_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-readonly) attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `disabled` attribute to an input element then the value of that element is not sent when you fire the "submit" action.
Try to remove the `disabled` attribute to get the field value.